How can the - script portion in .gitlab-ci.yml be configured to use CSH?
Considering the following .gitlab-ci.yml, how can I get the - script portion to effectively utilize CSH?
default:
  image: myimage:latest

test:
  script:
    - source csh.env
    - make

I've created a container image (myimage:latest) that defines ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/csh"] and when I start the container with docker/podman, the effective shell is CSH. The issue is when the gitlab-runner tries to run, it errors on the following during the "step_script" stage:
sh: No such file or directory.

I understand that I could just create a script in the repo, something like build.csh with appropriate interpreter, but that reduces the usefulness of the .gitlab-ci.yml. I've tried using entrypoint: [""], but that fails when sourcing the csh.env as the effective shell appears to fall back to "/bin/sh".
I found the following as a workaround, but would be nice to not have to do this.
default:
  image: myimage:latest
  entrypoint: [""]

test:
  script:
    - /bin/csh -c "source csh.env; env > .env"
    - while read LINE; do export "${LINE}" || continue; done < .env
    - make


According to the documentation these are the supported shells you can use with your GitLab Runner:

bash
sh
powershell
pwsh

It also states that you can set your preferred shell in the runners config.toml file as described here:
...
[[runners]]
  name = "shell executor runner"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
...

Maybe you could try to set
  shell = "csh"

there, but I'm not sure if this works since it is not a supported value of this field

Thanks, but I think this is changing the type of executor. I'm using the "docker" executor and trying to change the shell used within the docker container.

I just assumed this would solve the problem as you already described that the default shell in your docker is csh but gitlab still tries to access sh (which is the default I believe)
